# Переопределение поведения HttpClient

Tags: c#, .net

Задумал я исправить косяки родного HttpClient. Разумно предположить, что все методы сходятся к SendAsync, а значит нужно переопределять его в наследнике и даже виртуальный он.

Но оказалось, что виртуальная только одна его перегрузка, а внутренние методы HttpClient ходят через другие перегрузки и потому в наследник не попадают.

Это косяк разработчика класса HttpClient или я чего-то не понимаю в наследовании? Зачем объявлять одну перегрузку virtual, если перегружать ее бесполезно?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Все дело в том, что метод `SendAsync` не предназначен для расширения. И он не виртуальный, а override метод базового класса `HttpMessageInvoker`.

Расширять же `HttpClient` задумано через `HttpMessageHandler`/`DelegatingHandler` из которых (собственные реализации через наследование) можно составить цепочку декораторов последовательно обрабатывающих запрос.

Пример:

Проблема 1: `HttpClient` при таймауте кидает `OperationCanceledException`, что сбивает с толку и вызывает необходимость вручную проверять "действительно ли была отмена"

Пишем `FixTimeoutHandler` для подмены исключений. Увы, в `SendAsync` прокидывается **чужой** `CancellationToken` с чужим `CancellationTokenSource` (есть предположение, что реализация таймаута на нем построена), поэтому в конструктор прокидываем **родной** `CancellationToken` и у него проверяем "была ли реальная отмена"

```
public class FixTimeoutHandler : DelegatingHandler
{
    private CancellationToken _cancellationToken;

    public FixTimeoutHandler(
        HttpClientHandler innerHandler, 
        CancellationToken cancellationToken) : base(innerHandler)
    {
        _cancellationToken = cancellationToken;
    }

    protected override Task<HttpResponseMessage> SendAsync(HttpRequestMessage request,
        CancellationToken cancellationToken)
    {
        var requestTask = base.SendAsync(request, cancellationToken);

        var endTask = requestTask.ContinueWith(
            t =>
            {
                if (t.IsCanceled)
                {
                    //проверяем родной токен, а не тот, что нам дает метод
                    if (_cancellationToken.IsCancellationRequested)
                        throw new OperationCanceledException(cancellationToken);
                    throw new HttpRequestException("Timeout");
                }

                if (t.IsFaulted)
                {
                    var ex = t.Exception;
                    ex.Data["RequestUrl"] = request.RequestUri.ToString();
                    ex.Data["RequestMethod"] = request.Method.Method;
                    throw ex;
                }

                return t.Result;
            }, TaskContinuationOptions.ExecuteSynchronously
        );

        return endTask;
    }
}
```

Проблема 2: Повторять запрос при сетевых ошибках (в том числе и по таймауту, который мы хендлером `FixTimeoutHandler` определили в сетевые ошибки. Любая другая ошибка пролетит выше по стеку.

Упрощенная реализация

```
public class RepeatHandler : DelegatingHandler
{
    public RepeatHandler(HttpMessageHandler innerHandler) : base(innerHandler)
    {
    }

    protected override async Task<HttpResponseMessage> SendAsync(HttpRequestMessage request,
        CancellationToken cancellationToken)
    {
        for (var i = 0; i < 3; i++)
            try
            {
                var result = await base.SendAsync(request, cancellationToken).ConfigureAwait(true);
                return result;
            }
            catch (HttpRequestException){}

        throw new HttpRequestException("Error");
    }
}
```

Последний в цепочке `HttpClientHandler`, который делает http запросы.

Собираем вместе:

```
var cts = new CancellationTokenSource();
var http = new HttpClient(new RepeatHandler(new FixTimeoutHandler(new HttpClientHandler(),_cts.Token)))
{
    Timeout = TimeSpan.FromSeconds(3)
};
var result=await http.GetAsync("http://localhost/sleep.php", _cts.Token);
```

Также есть класс-фабрика [HttpClientFactory](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.net.http.httpclientfactory%28v=vs.118%29.aspx) для сбора цепочек хендлеров, но он лежит в отдельной сборке, которую нужно ставить через nuget

Comment: Ого, круто. А можно минимальный пример?

Comment: Решение первой проблемы приведет к тому, что на каждый запрос нужно будет создавать новый экземпляр `HttpClient`. Это, в свою очередь, может привести к другим проблемам (особенно, если вызовы очень частые): соединения не будут переиспользоваться, будут забиваться порты на машине (по умолчанию TCP-соединение живет 4 минуты). `HttpClient` был создан с расчетом на то, что он живет в течение  всей жизни приложения (на каждый сервис свой клиент).

Comment: @andreycha 1) с чего вдруг новый экземпляр? 2) Причем тут порты - новый порт рождается на коннект. Это ж не бд, что есть пул коннектов 3) HttpClient спроектирован на параллельные запросы..только это тут причем?

Comment: @andreycha понял почему новый экземпляр. Из-за передачи токена. Ну да, есть такое. Поэтому для себя я сделал полную обертку где свел все запросы в один метод. А можно токен не передавать, а проверять на каждом catch(OperationCanceledException)

Comment: Да, из-за токена. Цепочка тут простая: новый экземпляр на запрос -> новое соединение на запрос -> новый занятый порт. При определенной нагрузке может вылиться в то, что все порты окажутся заняты. Пример тут: http://www.nimaara.com/2016/11/01/beware-of-the-net-httpclient/

Comment: Но это я скорее не вам замечание делаю, а тем, кто это прочитает и захочет использовать :). У нас жеж тут "база знаний".

Comment: @andreycha, Подскажите пожалуйста, у меня HttpClient на все приложение живет. А DelegatingHandler живет на один запрос. Как мне быть? Что подскажете? Он, я так понимаю, умирает после первого запроса и приходится HttpClient пересоздавать

Comment: @Bretbas нет, хэндлер не умирает, достаточно его создавать один раз. В примере выше приходится создавать хэндлер (а за ним и клиент) только по той причине, что нужно просунуть оригинальный токен. Но, как упомянул vitidev, это ограничение тоже можно обойти.