# HttpClient вызывает TaskCanceledException

Tags: c#, .net-core, httpclient

Код ниже иногда(!) вызывает `TaskCanceledException`. Из-за чего такое происходит и как этого избежать? И если избежать не выйдет, то единственный путь - в `catch` повторно отправлять запрос?

```
        var client = _clientFactory.CreateClient();
        // Пробовал поставить client.Timeout = TimeSpan.FromMinutes(30);
        // Однако поток просто был залочен на полчаса, а потом вернул всё 
        // тот же TaskCanceledException

        HttpResponseMessage response = null;

        try
        {
            // request заранее определён. HttpMetod Post
            response = await client.SendAsync(request: request);
        }
        catch 
        {
            throw new NotImplementedException();
        }
```

**UPD**: Текст исключения

System.Threading.Tasks.TaskCanceledException: The operation was canceled.
 ---> System.IO.IOException: Unable to read data from the transport connection: Операция ввода/вывода была прервана из-за завершения потока команд или по запросу приложения..
 ---> System.Net.Sockets.SocketException (995): Операция ввода/вывода была прервана из-за завершения потока команд или по запросу приложения.
   --- End of inner exception stack trace ---
   at System.Net.Sockets.Socket.AwaitableSocketAsyncEventArgs.ThrowException(SocketError error, CancellationToken cancellationToken)
   at System.Net.Sockets.Socket.AwaitableSocketAsyncEventArgs.GetResult(Int16 token)
   at System.Net.Security.SslStream.g__InternalFillBufferAsync|215_0[TReadAdapter](TReadAdapter adap, ValueTask`1 task, Int32 min, Int32 initial)

   at System.Net.Security.SslStream.ReadAsyncInternal[TReadAdapter](TReadAdapter adapter, Memory`1 buffer)
   at System.Net.Http.HttpConnection.FillAsync()
   at System.Net.Http.HttpConnection.CopyToContentLengthAsync(Stream destination, UInt64 length, Int32 bufferSize, CancellationToken cancellationToken)
   at System.Net.Http.HttpConnection.ContentLengthReadStream.CompleteCopyToAsync(Task copyTask, CancellationToken cancellationToken)
   --- End of inner exception stack trace ---
   at System.Net.Http.HttpConnection.ContentLengthReadStream.CompleteCopyToAsync(Task copyTask, CancellationToken cancellationToken)
   at System.Net.Http.HttpConnectionResponseContent.SerializeToStreamAsync(Stream stream, TransportContext context, CancellationToken cancellationToken)
   at System.Net.Http.HttpContent.LoadIntoBufferAsyncCore(Task serializeToStreamTask, MemoryStream tempBuffer)
   at System.Net.Http.HttpClient.FinishSendAsyncBuffered(Task`1 sendTask, HttpRequestMessage request, CancellationTokenSource cts, Boolean disposeCts)
   at Post_v9.Classes.EBayAPI.SellAPI.FulfillmentAPI.EBayAPI_GetterOrders.GetOrders(IHttpClientFactory _clientFactory, String accessToken) in MyCode.cs:line 44

Comment: Текст исключения? Трассировка стека?

Comment: Это так срабатывает таймаут.

Comment: @tym32167 Обновил вопрос

Answer (score 3, accepted):

HttpClient при [таймауте бросает TaskCanceledException](https://github.com/dotnet/runtime/issues/21965), а не TimeoutException или HttpRequestException.

Видимо авторы считают верной метафору "операция запроса была ведь отменена (механизмом отмены по таймауту), значит TaskCanceledException". А может просто забыли обработать этот случай и обернуть исключение.

А потому приходится ловить это исключение при запросе и сверять CancellationToken.

Лично я считаю, что правильно кидать TimeoutHttpRequestException (наследник от HttpRequestException), как метафора "запрос не был успешен" и его можно перехватить и повторить, но если не нужно знать причину сбоя запроса, то не нужно писать лишний catch (как в случае с TimeoutException)

Как решал я

1. Делал метод расширение SendAsyncEx, где ловил исключение и кидал вместо него нужное мне (HttpRequestException).
2. Пытался сделать наследника HttpClient, где перегрузить метод SendAsync, но [безуспешно](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/641113/%D0%9F%D0%B5%D1%80%D0%B5%D0%BE%D0%BF%D1%80%D0%B5%D0%B4%D0%B5%D0%BB%D0%B5%D0%BD%D0%B8%D0%B5-%D0%BF%D0%BE%D0%B2%D0%B5%D0%B4%D0%B5%D0%BD%D0%B8%D1%8F-httpclient)
3. Сделать свой [DelegatingHandler](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/641113/%D0%9F%D0%B5%D1%80%D0%B5%D0%BE%D0%BF%D1%80%D0%B5%D0%B4%D0%B5%D0%BB%D0%B5%D0%BD%D0%B8%D0%B5-%D0%BF%D0%BE%D0%B2%D0%B5%D0%B4%D0%B5%D0%BD%D0%B8%D1%8F-httpclient), где подменять исключение. Работает, но это неудобный костыль.
4. Написал обертку над HttpClient - ей и пользуюсь. Но ее нельзя передать туда, где ждут родной HttpClient и про нее не знает IHttpClientFactory.

Comment: Можно на реализацию 4 варианта взглянуть?

Comment: @Anatoly она слишком петовая и для пет проектов - без тестов и туда напихано много всего, что лично мне мешало и ведет она себя не эквивалентно родному клиенту. Ну а в базовом варианте это обертка, где такие же методы, как в оборачиваемом HttpClient и они сводятся к SendAsync, который перехватывает TaskCanceledException и сверяет его с переданным токеном.

Comment: @Anatoly взгляните на [polly](http://www.thepollyproject.org/)

Comment: @Anatoly самое простое - сделать свои методы расширения и использовать **только их**. А если HttpClient внутри сторонней библиотеки, то придется перехватывать и переделывать такие исключения. Это плохой дизайн самого HttpClient. WTF в дотнете хватает (